# How do I add a MVC route to a specific controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My mind is somehow blank. How do I do this:

I have a `RegistrationController` and want the URL `/register` to hit the action `Register` on that controller. What do I have to add as a map route in global.asax?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, what you want is this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "RegisterRoute",
            "Register",
            new { controller = "Registration", action = "Register" }
        );
```

Now you can go to your page with an url like:

http://www.yoursite.com/register

Comment: You're right. It needs to only have "Register" in the URL definition. Thank you!

Comment: FYI if you have this code in your RouteConfig:

           routes.MapRoute(name: "Default",url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

be sure to put your custom route definition before this, so it gets picked up first

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "MyCustomRoute",                                              // Route name
                "Registration/Register",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Registration", action = "Register" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Comment: That would work only with the URL http://www.yoursite.com/Registration/Register. I believe Alex wants something like http://www.yoursite.com/Register.